# Adding checked items to a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how can i have a list of chosen values like this :
 
      . val 1 added
      . val 2 added
      . val 3 added
      . val 4 added
not working properly the result i got is in a single line :
      .val 1val 2val 3val 4 added
i'm a beginner in JS so could anyone help me to fix it thanks !

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('change', function() {
  var alsoInterested = '';

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value) {
    if (this.checked) {
  
      alsoInterested += ($(this).val());
    }
  });
  if (alsoInterested.length > 0) {
    alsoInterested =  alsoInterested + ' added' ;
  }

  $('#additionalChoices').html(alsoInterested);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="val 1">
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="val 2">
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="val 3">
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="val 4">
  <span class="lever"></span>
</label>

<div id="content">
  <ul>
    <li id="additionalChoices"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So you actually want a LI element for every result? Or put all the multilined results into a single LI?

Comment: yes exactly every result in one element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all your inputs, and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to an Array of LI elements that can later be appended:

```js
const $ckb = $('.cb');
const $choices = $('#additionalChoices');

$ckb.on('change', function() {
  const LIs = $ckb.get().reduce((arr, EL) => {
    if (EL.checked) arr.push( $("<li>", {text: EL.value}) );
    return arr;
  }, []);
  $choices.html(LIs);
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="val 1"> 1 </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="val 2"> 2 </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="val 3"> 3 </label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb" value="val 4"> 4 </label>

<ul id="additionalChoices"></ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

PS.

- Label element is not meant to enclose more than one ActionElement. So beware.
- Use [jQuery `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), not the deprecated `.bind()`

Comment: Noted ! Thanks for your help